# readint nasm linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, int, nasm

Is there a way / system call / a function that lets me read numbers from stdin into a register?

currently I can read in a string of, say, 9 characters.

This is, unfortunately, not what I was looking for since my number could be of variable length (so long it is representable in assembly)

e.g. I want to be able to input "5" as well as "66785949" as well as negative numbers like "-1123534", and have it correctly represented as an actual number in assembly, not a string.

I've been looking everywhere so I decided to ask here.

If there's no easy way to do it, is it possible to use C's input/output function library into my linux nasm assembly code? How would I do that and how would I call one of these functions to get a number from stdin?

Thanks

Comment: You can always do it yourself. Remember that 66785949 = ((((((6 * 10 + 6) * 10 + 7) * 10 + 8) * 10 + 5) * 10 + 9) * 10 + 4) * 10 + 9.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no system call to do it. Yes, you can easily call atoi(), if you don't feel like implementing it yourself. You just need to link to the C library (`-lc`) and declare the external symbol (`extern atoi`).